# Applying an oEmbed filter to a custom post type

Tags: oembed

I have a function in my functions.php file which takes any embedded YouTube URL, appends `&rel=0` to the end of the URL, and wraps it in a `<div>`. It works perfectly for YouTube URLs I paste into any page or post:

```
function embed_youtube_parameters( $code ) {
    if( strpos( $code, 'youtu.be' ) !== false || strpos( $code, 'youtube.com' ) !== false || strpos( $code, 'youtube-nocookie.com' ) !== false ) {
        $return = preg_replace( '@embed/([^"&]*)@', 'embed/$1&rel=0', $code );
    }
    return '<div class="video-container">' . $return . '</div>';
}
add_filter( 'embed_oembed_html', 'embed_youtube_parameters' );
```

I also have a custom post type (added via a plugin I use), which has a filter that I can use to customise the output of the single custom post type pages it generates. So I have that filter also in my functions.php file.

It's quite a long filter, but part of it looks like this:

```
<?php if ( get_cpt_meta( 'cpt_video_link' ) ) : ?>
<div class="cpt-video">
    <?php echo wp_oembed_get( get_cpt_meta( 'cpt_video_link' ) ); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The custom post type uses a bunch of custom fields, one of which is for a YouTube URL (`cpt_video_link`). So the part of the filter I've shown above should echo the YouTube URL using `wp_oembed_get`, which - as far as I understand it - should work the same as pasting a YouTube URL onto a regular page or post - in the sense that it's using oEmbed.

My assumption is that - because it's using oEmbed - it should therefore also work with my `embed_youtube_parameters` function (above), meaning that it should have `&rel=0` appended to the end of the URL, and wrapped in the `<div class="video-container">`.

However this is not the case, and I can't figure out why. My goal is for the `embed_youtube_parameters` function to be applied to my CPT filter. Can anyone give me some pointers as to why this isn't happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the code reference for [`wp_oembed_get`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_oembed_get/) (and [`WP_oEmbed::get_html()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_oembed/get_html/)) I don't think [`embed_oembed_html`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/embed_oembed_html/) fitler gets fired when that function is called. But I might have missed something.

You could try using [`WP_Embed::shortcode( array $attr, string $url = '' )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_embed/shortcode/) instead of `wp_oembed_get` as this would mimic what happens with the native post types and the filter would get fired, I think.

Something like this. **Updated 23.12.19**

```
<?php if ( get_cpt_meta( 'cpt_video_link' ) ) : ?>
  <div class="cpt-video">
    <?php
      $embed = new WP_Embed();
      echo $embed->shortcode(array(), get_cpt_meta( 'cpt_video_link' ));
    ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! It makes sense that the `embed_oembed_html` filter isn't fired when `wp_oembed_get` is called. However, I'm afraid your suggestion doesn't work either: I now get a "wp-die-message" text displayed on the page in place of the YouTube video. The text says "There has been a critical error on your website." Any idea why?

Comment: @GermanKiwi, I'm afraid not. Have you enabled WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_LOG  to see what causes the error? Maybe the class is missing some data and caused the error.

Comment: Good tip. I've just enabled both DEBUG modes and now it shows me this error on the page:

Deprecated: Non-static method WP_Embed::shortcode() should not be called statically in /path/to/my/functions.php on line 45

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /path/to/wp-includes/class-wp-embed.php:152 Stack trace: #0 /path/to/my/functions.php(45): WP_Embed::shortcode(Array, 'https://www.you...') #1 /path/to/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(288): {closure}('\t<div class="wp...', Object(WP_Post)) (etc etc)

Comment: @GermanKiwi Sorry, my bad, of course that's the reason *(facepalm)*. So, before the echo do `$embed = new WP_Embed();` to init a new instance of the class. Then `echo $embed->shortcode(array(), get_cpt_meta( 'cpt_video_link' ));` to use the class method. I'm not sure, if there already is an instance of the embed class in some global variable, or do you always have to initialize a new instance of it yourself every time you need it.

Comment: Thanks so much - that worked perfectly! Perhaps you could update your answer above to include this? Then I can mark it as the answer. :)

Comment: @GermanKiwi Good to hear. I've updated my answer.